# how to add together the values ​from the RPN algorithm

Tags: java, calculator, postfix-notation

I’m writing calculator that calculates values ​​from expressions:

> 3+(23/24)*34/24

I used RPN algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

I have now sorted expression in String:

> 3 23 24 / 34 * 24 / +

I don't have any idea how can I get value from this expression.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic algorithm is based on a stack-like structure

For each token in the expression:

- if it is a number: push it
- if it is a symbol: pop 2 values; do the matched operation; push the result

E.g.:

```
"3 23 24 / 34 * 24 / +"
                                             Stack
3:  push 3                                   |   3
23: push 23                                  |   3    23
24: push 24                                  |   3    23     24
/:  pop (24),   pop (23),    push 23/24      |   3     0.95
34: push 34                                  |   3     0.95  34
*:  pop (34),   pop (0.95),  push 0.95*34    |   3    32.58
24: push 24                                  |   3    32.58  24
/:  pop (24),   pop (32.58), push 32.58/24   |   3     1.35
+:  pop (1.35), pop (3),     push 3+1.35     |   4.35
```

The last value that remains in the stack is the result

Comment: I already have postfix I want to get value from Postfix: 3 23 24 / 34 * 24 / + =4,357638889

Comment: @TomaszOkraszewski Can you please be more specific on how this answer does not meet your question?

Comment: sorry, you are right. There is answer in front of my nose.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea behind RPN is that there is a stack that all the arguments get put on, then taken off for an operation.

For this set, the basic flow will be:

| Element | Stack | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| push 3 | 3 |  |  |
| push 23 | 3,23 |  |  |
| push 24 | 3,23,24 |  |  |
| -divide |  |  |  |
| pop b | 3,23 |  | 24 |
| pop a | 3 | 23 | 24 |
| push a/b | 3, 0.9583 |  |  |
| end-divide |  |  |  |
| push 34 | 3, 0.9583, 34 |  |  |
| -multiply |  |  |  |
| pop b | 3, 0.9583 |  | 34 |
| pop a | 3 | 0.9583 | 34 |
| push a*b | 3, 32.5833 |  |  |
| end-multiply |  |  |  |
| push 24 | 3, 32.5833, 24 |  |  |
| -divide |  |  |  |
| pop b | 3, 32.5833 |  | 24 |
| pop a | 3 | 32.5833 | 24 |
| push a/b | 3, 1.3576 |  |  |
| end-divide |  |  |  |
| add |  |  |  |
| pop b | 3 |  | 1.3576 |
| pop a |  | 3 | 1.3576 |
| push a+b | 4.3576 |  |  |
| end-add |  |  |  |

pop solution!

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Could you reword it perhaps?

Comment: sorry, It's answer.